# How to use HIVE to take a text file with several fields, and split it into several files based on month and year, then put these files in directories

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 7 text files with about 1million lines each, and I need to split all of these files based on the month and year then place them into directories in HDFS.

So for example lines with the date: 2015-01-06 would go into 2015/1

I have tried putting all 7 files into a directory, creating a table, then using the command:

```
insert overwrite local directory /table select * from table where YEAR(DATE)= 2015 AND MONTH(DATE) =01
```

however, it takes ages to process and this would make it so I have to do each month individually which I don't want to do.

Would it potentially be easier to do this with the Command line or with the Java interface using a JAR file?

Comment: create another table partitione by yyyy-MM, insert overwrite it with calculated yyyy-MM with dynamic partition load. Partitions are folders in hdfs

Comment: In order to partition will the table I create need to have a year and month column?

Comment: one column calculate it as your date substring to get yyyy-MM and use it as a partition col